# Using TFIDF with Naive bayes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, tf-idf, naivebayes

I'm building a sentiment classification model using TFIDF and naive bayes. But the model keeps misclassifying the second class.Although I have used TFIDf with other models such as SVM and random forest and it was working fine. Below I will describe my data and steps used: I have 2000 comments (1000 positive, 1000 negative). I did the following steps:
 1) data preprocessing

```
cleanTextData = erasePunctuation(textData);
cleanTextData = lower(cleanTextData);
words = stopWords;
cleanDocuments = tokenizedDocument(cleanTextData);
cleanDocuments = removeWords(cleanDocuments,words);
cleanDocuments = normalizeWords(cleanDocuments);  
cleanDocuments(1:10)
%% Bag of Words
cleanBag = bagOfWords(cleanDocuments)
cleanBag = removeInfrequentWords(cleanBag,2) % remove words with frequency less than or equal 2
%% remove emplty documents caused by preprocessing
[cleanBag,idx] = removeEmptyDocuments(cleanBag);
```

Then I used TFIDF

```
predictors = tfidf(cleanBag,'Normalized',true,'TFWeight','log','IDFWeight','smooth');
```

Then I passed the results to my naive bayes model

```
t = templateNaiveBayes('DistributionNames','mvmn');
CVMdl = fitcecoc(predictors,response,'KFold',10,'Learners',t,'FitPosterior',true,'Coding','onevsone','ResponseName','response');
```

But the confusion matrix will give the following results :

```
C1     C2
 ____    __
  990    10
 1000     0
```

It seems it is classifying almost all the 2000 observations to one class only. Please advice, I have tried changing the K fold value.Also I have tried diferent types of distrebution such as Multivariate multinomial distribution, Multinomial distribution, kernel, and Normal (Gaussian) distribution.Also I tried normalising the data. But all me attempts had no effect on enhancing the model. 
Using Naive bayes without TFIDF will give 0.7536 F-measure which is somehow is considered good.
My concern is if I'm using TF-IDF with naive bayes in the correct way.Because it is misclassified all observations of the second class.

Comment: You should mention what you have tried, and what research you have done, so people who want to help don't waste their time repeating that.

Comment: I meant that I tried the several arguments as shown in the code but they didn't make a difference.             CVMdl = fitcecoc(predictors,response,'KFold',10,'Learners',t,'FitPosterior',true,'Coding','onevsone','ResponseName','response');

Comment: The idea is to tell us _in the question_ what you have tried. Comments can be deleted.